# Jupyter Notebook - How to hide everything except notebooks on main screen?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I don't use Jupyter as much as I want to, but I am going to start doing it as I want to write reports with my code.

When I launch into the main screen though, I am presented with 'all' the files on my computer which makes finding the notebooks a little harder and it is messy (I know, first world problems!)

Is there any way of hiding everything except my notebooks?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit of stepping aside, but you can create a folder with your notebooks, then launch jupyter notebook from the command line, after setting yourself in that folder.

```
$ cd my_notebooks
my_notebooks$ jupyter notebook
```

At launch, the window will only show the files residing in that folder.

Comment: Excellent, thank you VERY much Reblochon, very helpful. I will do that now :)